# How to import bookmarks from HTML in Firefox?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, bookmarks

When I need to import the bookmarks in Firefox, I usually go to **bookmarks > see all** and then click on the import button, but in 11.10 it is not there anymore.

How can I import bookmarks from a HTML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if you can access:

1. Open Firefox and hover over the top left bar, under Bookmarks,
   select Show All Bookmarks.
2. Maximize the Library window.
3. Click onto the Library window at the top to select it, now the top
   menu changes as you hover over the top left bar again, select Import
   and Backup and import your HTML.

Comment: This did not work with 11.10/FF8 - until I maximized the Library window. Possibly a bug?
Thanks for the tip - I wouldn't have pursued it further had I not thought the menus should be there.